# Probabilistic Robotics Exercise

Tags: probability-distributions, quadratics

I am reading [Probabilistic Robotics](http://www.probabilistic-robotics.org/) and I don't know how to solve the exercise problem number 4 at the end of the second chapter. There are no solutions to this text.

**The exercise states:**

> In this exercise we will apply Bayes rule to Gaussians. Suppose we are
>   a mobile robot who lives on a long straight road. Our location *x*
>   will simply be the position along this road. Now suppose that
>   initially, we believe to be at location *x<sub>init</sub> = 1000m*,
>   but we happen to know that this estimate is uncertain. Based on this
>   uncertainty, we model our initial belief by a Gaussian with variance
>   *σ<sup>2</sup><sub>init</sub> = 900m<sup>2</sup>*.
>
> To find out more about our location, we query a GPS receiver. The GPS
>   tells us our location is *z<sub>GPS</sub> = 1100m*. This GPS receiver
>   is known to have an error variance of *σ<sup>2</sup><sub>init</sub> =
>   100m<sup>2</sup>*.
>
> **(a)** Write the probability density functions of the prior *p(x)* and the measurement *p(z|x)*.
>
> **(b)** Using Bayes Rule, what is the posterior *p(x|z)*? Can you prove it to be Gaussian?

P.S.: This chapter talks about Recursive State Estimation using Bayes Filter Algorithm and also this exercise hints that it is plain manipulation of Quadratics..

What I have so far is that:

- *p(x)* is a normal distribution (gaussian) with *mean=1000m* and *σ<sup>2</sup> = 900m<sup>2</sup>*.
- I'm thinking that *p(z|x)* is a normal distribution with mean=x and *σ<sup>2</sup> =
  100m<sup>2</sup>*.

Any help will be greatly appreciated..Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right so far. $p(x) \sim \mathcal{N}(1000m, 900m^2)$. And $p(z|x) \sim \mathcal{N}(x, 100m^2)$

About **(b)**: Bayes' rule is pretty easy and gives you: $p(x|z) = \frac{p(z|x) p(x)}{p(z)} $

You can prove this to be a Gaussian by writing the Gaussian formula down. First look at the exponent and prove that they stay quadratic and what the new mean and variance has become. Then, show that the normaliser is that of a Guassian and that the variance matches the one from the exponent.

Comment: So what I have now is: $(200pi)^{-0.5}e^{-0.5(\frac{(x-1000)^{2}}{900}+\frac{(z-x)^{2}}{100})}$

Comment: Where do I go from now? I can't transform my exponent into the gaussian form: $\frac{(x-μ)^{2}}{2σ^2}$.. also, in the above: it is not $(200pi)^{−0.5}$..it is $(900*100pi)^{-0.5}$

Comment: Also I am assuming that $p(z)$ is a constant and I'm ignoring it (that's probably wrong :p )..

Comment: No, that is correct. $p(z)$ is a constant in respect to $x$.

Comment: So I have something like that: $η*(200pi)^{-0.5}*(1800pi)^{-0.5}*e^{-0.5*(x-1000)^2/900}*e^{-0.5*(z-x)^2/100}$ . How am I going to prove that this thing is a Gaussian? And what will be the new mean and $σ^2$?? Thanks a lot anyway..

Comment: Take all the $e^{...} e^{...}$ and look only at the exponent, to get something like $-\dfrac{1}{2}((x-1000)^2 + (x -z)^2)$. Multiply this out, and then bring it in the form of $(x-\mu_{new})^2 / \sigma_{new}$.

Comment: So I get this: $e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(10x^2-2000x+10^6+9z^2-18z x)}{900}}$, which with some manipulation gets to: $e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x^2-100-0.9z)^2+10^4+0.09z^2-180z}{90}}$, which can also be written as: $e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-100-0.9z)^2}{90}}*e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{10^4+0.09z^2-180z}{90}}$ which goes to: $e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-100-0.9z)^2}{90}}*η$, where $η$ is a constant in respect to $x$. Is this correct? Can I say that this is a Gaussian with $μ=100+0.9z$ and $σ^2=90$?

Comment: Exactly! (Although, you would also need to prove that $\nu$ is the right constant as you would get if it were a Gaussian with your mean and variance as you wrote it.)

Comment: But the constant is of the form: $\frac{(4*pi^2*100*900)^{-\frac{1}{2}}*e^{-const}}{p(z)}$ ..where $p(z)$ is constant in respect to $x$.. What would I do? The best I could do is to bring into the form of: $η*(2*pi*90)^{-\frac{1}{2}}*e^{gaussianStaff}$..Is that ok?

Comment: Where of course $gaussianStaff= -\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-100-0.9z)^2}{90}$ .. So the result seems ok to me.. It is a gaussian multiplied by a constant..But I don't know for sure..

Answer (score 0):

As a general answer to your question:

Somebody has worked out the solutions of *Probabilistic Robotics* (included Chapter 2) and has uploaded them to GitHub.

https://github.com/pptacher/probabilistic_robotics

Disclaimer: I have not checked the correctness of the solutions.